# Is this really the logo of the North Korean space program?

Tags: terminology, reference-request, north-korea, insignia

Reading about the North Korean space program, and its recent launch of the [Kwangmyŏngsŏng-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kwangmy%C5%8Fngs%C5%8Fng-4) satellite, I stumbled upon this logo:

[image: North Korea Space Program Logo, saying 'NADA']

It is referenced in quite a few news stories, like [here](http://www.collectspace.com/news/news-040214a-north-korea-nada-space-agency.html) or [here](http://www.cnet.com/news/north-korea-names-space-agency-nada-mimics-nasa-logo/#!), or [here](http://www.foxnews.com/science/2014/04/03/north-korea-nada-space-agency-logo-are-anything-but-nothing.html).

I am, however, a little in doubt about this one. The main reason is the acronym "NADA" (National Aerospace Development Administration). That really does sound like a pun, meaning "nothing" in Spanish, and the word is used about the same concept in several other languages. Also, the agency is much more often referred to as "Korean Committee of Space Technology" (KCST), so why the sudden change of name? However, some sites, like [North Korea Tech](http://www.northkoreatech.org/tag/national-aerospace-development-administration/) uses that name, and the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Aerospace_Development_Administration) exists.

Honestly, I can not tell if this is a joke or not, as you never know when talking about North Korea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Among others, the Wikipedia page cites [this CNET article](http://www.cnet.com/news/north-korea-names-space-agency-nada-mimics-nasa-logo/), which in turn links to a copy of the original KCNA statement; this is also linked from the WP page. It's now offline, but [here is an archived copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20140406054614/http://www.kcna.co.jp/item/2014/201403/news31/20140331-24ee.html). No image (possibly didn't archive) but the text confirms a) the name and b) the logo.

> The National Aerospace Development Administration (NADA) is the country's central guidance institution organizing all the space development projects.
>
> Its mission is to put into practice the idea and principle of the DPRK government to develop the space for peaceful purpose.
>
> The emblem of the NADA was recently instituted, which represents its character, mission, position and development prospects.
>
> Seen in the lower part of the globe-shaped dark blue emblem are white-colored letters "Kukgaujugaebalkuk" (National Aerospace Development Administration) in Korean and in its upper part light blue-colored letters "DPRK" with the Great Bear above them. Printed in its middle are white-colored letters "NADA" in English.
>
> Two light blue-colored rings intercrossing the emblem symbolize satellite orbits.

KCST seems to have been the previous body which carried out space roles, now closed and rolled into NADA.

Comment: What makes this even more puzzling is that the NK announcement came on April 1 2014, even though it seems to be legit.

Comment: I wonder why four ASCII characters (or four letters of the Latin Alphabet) which a [huge fraction of the planet uses](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Latin_alphabet_world_distribution.svg) is referred to as "*in English*".

Comment: Because it's the abbreviation of an English term. In French the abbreviation is probably ADAN.

Comment: It would be ANDA in French.

Comment: I vote this should be moved to French acronyms SE (er, I mean ES d'aF)